# Setting Date to Europe/London and Inserting into Database

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli, prepared-statement

My site will be running locally in Europe/London time and so I want to insert the date and time for when they registered according to this timezone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$rtime = date("Y-m-d H:ia", time());
$online = 1;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `password` ,`email` , `nickname`, `registered`, `online`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $username, $password, $email, $nickname, $rtime, $online);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }
```

When I run this script the date/time still shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: thats nice. What is your question?

Comment: Yes, what is the quesiton?

Comment: What type is your `registered` column?

Comment: make the first parameter of the bind_param function as 'sssssi' may be this can work i am not sure.

Comment: Yeah your $rtime is not an int change its bind_param type to to "s"

Comment: It is set to DATETIME but I'm not sure if this is right or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about something like **Timestamp**

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$timestamp =  $date->getTimestamp();
```

Use **Unix timestamp** to save time in database

When you bring this timestamp from database, So covert back like..

```
date('m/d/Y', 1299446702);
```